camera project image onto CAD object
I am trying to project on image onto a CAD object using python. I know it is possible in Blender or other 3d softwares, but was trying to find a way to do it in python. Does anyone have any suggestions what libraries or functions to look at? I have been trying to find something but most are going from 3d to 2d, so the opposite of what I am looking for from what I understand. If there is a better stack site to ask please let me know. Here is a video of what I am trying to do being done in blender.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ua8CrGf6wP8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnE9XOGSvSM
